# Filtering a model in Django based on a condition upon the latest child record

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have two models like this:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Order(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    success = models.BooleanField()
```

I would like to filter all the records from the `Store` model whose latest order was successful i.e. `success == True`.

Although it looks very simple, I'm having issues figuring how I would accomplish this using the ORM query system.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Or do you need a single query? Is a solution for you make 2 queries: Take last orderdate for each sotore and check if exists a `success` order for this data and store is a solution? A loop is a valid solution for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach is this: do 2 lists, first one with (id_store, last_success_date) tuples and second one with (id_store, last_date) tuples:

```
l_succ = stores.objects.filter( 
                       order__success = True 
                  ).annotate(
                       last_success=Max('order__date')
                  ).value_list (
                       'id', 'last_success'
                  )
#l_succ = [ (1, '1/1/2011'), (2, '31/12/2010'), ... ] <-l_succ result

l_last = stores.objects.annotate(
                       last_date=Max('order__date')
                  ).value_list (
                       'id', 'last_date'
                  )
#l_last = [ (1, '1/1/2011'), (2, '3/1/2011'), ... ]   <-l_last result
```

Then take store ids for stores that last data and last success date are equals, and you have the query:

```
store_success_ids =  [ k[0] for k in l_succ if k in l_last ]
#store_success_ids = [1, 5, ... ]          <-store_success_ids result
#Cast l_last to dictionary to do lookups if you have a lot of stores.

result = Store.objects.filter( pk__in = store_success_ids)
```

It seems an elegant solution, only four lines of code for a complex query (but with a simple requeriment). Disclaimer, it is not tested.

Comment: HI DaniHP, this solved it for me. I used a similar solution. It doesn't look like it is possible to do this one single query. Bummer. (Sometimes the ORM really makes me feel DB dumb.)

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea, so dont beat me if I am totally wrong :)
I thought you could do something like this:

```
# first annotate latest order to Store which returns new queryset, filter new qs
# by success = True
stores = Store.objects.annotate(Max('order__date')).filter(order__success=True)
```

This is untested to be honest.

Comment: That looks very promising. Here's a link to the docs for info on this concept: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one query.

Use the [.extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) functionality of QuerySets to write SQL that looks something like this:

```
Store.objects.extra(where=['id in (select store_id from order where success = true)'])
```

Comment: This doesn't check if success Order is the latest - this query will return Store with at least one success Order. Also extra isn't needed here: `Store.objects.filter(order__success=True)` will do the same (or something like this, haven't tested it).

Comment: Can you do order_-success=True if Order is not included in the Store model? You are right about the latest point. You can check if the latest order was a success by modifying the extra() in query appropriately.

Comment: M, yes I can, these two models are connected: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships. Or I don't understand something and it's not applicable here? What about modifying `extra`, what's your solution? I'm curious to know the answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

Would this approach work for you? Loop over all of the stores and grab the latest success for each store if one exists.

My original idea that wasn't correct:

```
latest_successes = []
store_objects = Store.objects.all()
for store_obj in store_objects:
    try:
        latest_success = Order.objects.filter(store=store_obj).filter(success=True).order_by('-date')[0]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    else:
        latest_successes.append(latest_success)
```

Edit based on solid comment from @demalexx

```
latest_successes = []
store_objects = Store.objects.all()
for store_obj in store_objects:
    try:
        is_latest_success = store_obj.order_set.order_by('-date')[0].success
    except IndexError:
        pass
    else:
        latest_successes.append(store_obj)
```

Comment: This won't work: you select latest success order, but there could be more recent unsuccess order. Need to modify it: `is_latest_success = store_obj.order_set.order_by('-date')[0].success`. And this is very ineffective: new query for each Store object. But it depends on OP task, it could work well in some cases.

Comment: That's a great point about the possibility for a more recent order that was unsuccessful. I hadn't thought of that. I don't agree that the proposed methodology is ineffective based on "new query for each Store object" but I do agree that it is likely not the most efficient method (or at least I hope someone posts something that is more efficient).

Comment: What I meant by ineffective, suppose you have a million Stores - you'll get a million SQL requests, not the most effective way to solve the problem :) Also OP didn't tell anything about time limits, if he needs it in real-time, like prepare this list in a view, it's inappropriate solution.

Comment: @demalexx I'm with you for sure. I was just being pedantic about ineffective versus inefficient. But ineffective would be absolutely correct if runtime were to approach the age of the universe =). BTW does my revision look correct to you now.

Comment: @demalexx incidentally can you point me to the docs that explain your use of order_set. I'm assuming that based on the foreign key relationship we can access each stores set of orders but I want to be sure I understand the syntax correctly.

Comment: Yes, probably bad word using, but you get the idea :) Docs about accessing related objects: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference. Your code won't work - if latest order is unsuccessfull store will be added too. I think you know how to fix it :)